# Sent email on two different box in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Can you help me?

I use SwiftMail and Mailtrap as smtp-server for all message (all emails sends from my project to one inbox in Mailtrip), but now I need send email in another email-box (for automatic testing). Best solution is make forward emails from Mailtrap to my QA-email. But in Mailtrap this is a paid feature. And I want to make it programmatic.

I already tried add one more mailer into config - Gmail's smtp

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: gmail_mailer
    mailers:
        mailtrip_mailer:
            transport: "%mailer_transport%"
            host:      "%mailtrip_mailer_host%"
            username:  "%mailtrip_mailer_user%"
            password:  "%mailtrip_mailer_password%"
            port:      "%mailtrip_mailer_port%"
            spool:  { type: memory }
        gmail_mailer:
            transport:  "%mailer_transport%"
            host:       "%gmail_mailer_host%"
            username:   "%gmail_mailer_user%"
            password:   "%gmail_mailer_password%"
            port:       "%gmail_mailer_port%"
            encryption: "%gmail_mailer_encryption%"
            spool:  { type: memory }
```

Tried add [Specified Address](https://symfony.com/doc/master/email.html#sending-to-a-specified-address-but-with-exceptions) delivery_addresses: `['%admin_email%']` - but email didn't sent, no matter what provider I use.

I can add one more mailer (Gmail) and use it for sending emails and send emails twice with loop - one to Gmail-inbox, and other to QA-email (with adding into TO-param my QA-email) - but is little bit wrong solution. 
How will it be best practice to implemented this?

Comment: I'm quite confused by the varying concepts you throw around. mailers are always *senders*, it shouldn't matter **to** which mail address you send an email, only **from** which it is sent. I don't know, what your automatic testing is like, but if it's not on your production server, you might just want to set different env variables and be done with it. it's really confusing what you *actually* want to do, also you provide no code to be examined. Also, if there is a fundamental problem with *sending* of your emails, there should be logs (maybe set them up properly).

Comment: @Jakumi Mailtrap it service like proxy for emails - all emails (no matter what is in TO-field) sent in one sandbox in my account in Mailtrap. But now I need sent emails to another email address but as I'm use smpt of Mailtrap so I can't. But idea with env parameter could help me - I'll check it.